# getting backbone to serve static html files

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here is the directory structure on my server

> public/js/...
>
> ```
>   /css/...
>   /img/...
>   /demo
>   /demo/button/index.html
>   /demo/slider/index.html
>   /demo/dialogBox/index.html
> ```

In normal backbone route handler, I need to create a view object in which, there is a model. The model will fetch data from REST API upon initialization. But when it comes to static pages, I am a bit confused since I am still in learning stage.

Question:

How to configure the backbone router to serve the static html pages under demo folder?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: you don't.

The (simplified) way a website (using Backbone) works is:

1. Client requests a page from the web server
2. Web server sends page (sometimes including a Backobne app)
3. Client receives web page, web browser renders page (executing Backbone code, if any)
4. Backbone router handles hash changes and updates data on the page (possibly making ajax requests), without ever requesting a new page from the server

Backbone doesn't do anything with static pages: the client requests them (e.g. by clicking on a link), and the web server sends them. In other words, it follows the steps above, but stops at step 3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think it is where I can't think through myself. But even Backbone app needs to provide link to static resources, e.g.: .png file in /public/img/banner.png. If it is allowed, we can just replace banner.png with banner.html and open it in new browser window. Does it work?